# pmap _df: Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, tidyverse, purrr

I thought the `map_df` family can fully replace `plyr::ldply`, as the release note in `purrr` package claimed a long time ago. However, I'm quite frustrated to realize that I cannot find a simple and elegant solution in this case.

```
params <- tribble(
  ~mean, ~sd,
    5,     1,
   10,     5,
   -3,    10)

params %>% 
    pmap_dfr(rnorm, n = 5)
```

An error message will be returned:

```
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names
```

This is because that *_df function uses `dplyr::bind_rows`, and `bind_rows` only allows named lists, which cannot and is unnecessary to meet in the example above.

To get a data frame, the simplest way I can think of is using

```
params %>% 
    pmap(rnorm, n = 5) %>%
    ldply
```

Therefore, my question is: is there a simpler way to use ONLY functions in `purrr` (or within tidyverse) to achieve the resulting dataframe I need? Thanks!